# Why does the for loop here print everything twice and then list values out of range?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, request, iteration

I have a set of code that sends a request to SnapToRoads Api. The length of the data set in this case is around 27, but the 'originalIndex' shown goes up to 53

```
results = requests.get("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=12.919082641601562,77.65169525146484|12.919082641601562,77.65169525146484|12.918915748596191,77.6517105102539|12.918915748596191,77.6517105102539|12.918656349182129,77.65177154541016|12.918656349182129,77.65177154541016|12.918524742126465,77.6517562866211|12.918524742126465,77.6517562866211|12.918295860290527,77.65178680419922|12.918295860290527,77.65178680419922|12.918216705322266,77.65177154541016|12.918216705322266,77.65177154541016|12.918027877807617,77.65178680419922|12.918027877807617,77.65178680419922|12.917914390563965,77.65178680419922|12.917914390563965,77.65178680419922|12.917774200439453,77.65178680419922|12.917774200439453,77.65178680419922|12.917659759521484,77.65179443359375|12.917659759521484,77.65179443359375|12.917553901672363,77.65180969238281|12.917553901672363,77.65180969238281|12.917448043823242,77.6518325805664|12.917448043823242,77.6518325805664|12.917227745056152,77.65177917480469|12.917227745056152,77.65177917480469|12.91706657409668,77.65178680419922|12.91706657409668,77.65178680419922|12.916943550109863,77.65178680419922|12.916943550109863,77.65178680419922|12.916749000549316,77.65178680419922|12.916749000549316,77.65178680419922|12.916621208190918,77.65179443359375|12.916621208190918,77.65179443359375|12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.91647720336914,77.65180206298828|12.916269302368164,77.65177154541016|12.916269302368164,77.65177154541016|12.916149139404297,77.65178680419922|12.916149139404297,77.65178680419922|12.916014671325684,77.65177917480469|12.916014671325684,77.65177917480469|12.91580867767334,77.65179443359375|12.91580867767334,77.65179443359375|12.915785789489746,77.65182495117188|12.915785789489746,77.65182495117188|12.915775299072266,77.65180969238281|12.915775299072266,77.65180969238281|12.915729522705078,77.65179443359375|12.915729522705078,77.65179443359375|12.91568374633789,77.65179443359375|12.91568374633789,77.65179443359375&key=AIzaSyAmplaUG26XJGwPrLbky2bHQ-eBmQvZUVU")
snappoints = results.json()['snappedPoints']
snapdata = set()
for point in snappoints:
    # this is each individual element in snapPoints array
    snapdata.add(point['originalIndex'])
print (snapdata)
length = len(snapdata)
print (length)
```

I want to correspond the data I have with the original indices by seeing which ones are retained, but the API shows more indices than which the request is sent. please help. Thanks

PS: I'm a noob with APIs

Seemingly the for loop is messed up:

```
api1 = []
for i in range(0, length-1):
    dataPoint = data[i]
    dataPoint1 = data [i+1]
    coordinate = dataPoint['coordinates']
    coordinate1 = dataPoint1['coordinates']
    x = coordinate[0]
    y = coordinate[1]
    x1 = coordinate1[0]
    y1 = coordinate1[1]

    str1 = str(x)
    str2 = str(y)
    str3 = '|'
    apiData = str1 + ',' + str2 + str3
    apiData = apiData+ (str1 + ',' + str2 + str3)
    print (apiData)
    api1.append(apiData)
    i +=1    
print (api1)
print (len(api1))
```

Comment: Count your `Requests` Parameter, you send **54** and Response are even **54**. All your Data are **doubled**!!

Comment: Yeahhh thanks a lot! My bad, len (the data) gave me 27. But the weird thing is that there is no data repetition :/. I ran a for loop in order to get the data in this format.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your `for loop ...`.

Comment: Done... please have a look. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit of doubling Points!

```
apiData = apiData+ (str1 + ',' + str2 + str3)
```

`apiData` has already `str1 + ',' + str2 + str3`, you assign `apiData` again.
Removing this Line will fix Doubling.

Your `print (len(api1))` count the Doubled String, therefore you see **27**.

To see the Real Count of Points, use the following:

```
print(len(api1.split('|')))
```

Comment: Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)